# How can I know that user just renewed a google play subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

I'm working with google play subscription and couldn't figure out how to know when user renewed the plan for one more period. I'm giving 3 credit's to use one feature  of my app, and each month the user would receive 3 more credit's if renewed the subscription.
I'm monitoring the user plan using this method below, but it caches the user subscription for a while, so I'm afraid of giving the user 3 more credits when he actually did not renewed the subscription.

```
fun queryPurchases() {
    val purchasesResult = mBillingClient?.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
    if (mBillingClient?.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS)?.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        if (purchasesResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            purchasesResult.purchasesList?.addAll(
                    purchasesResult.purchasesList)
        }
    }

    if (purchasesResult != null && purchasesResult.purchasesList != null) {
        if (purchasesResult.purchasesList.isEmpty()){
            purchasedPlan.postValue(null)
        }else {
            purchasedPlan.postValue(purchasesResult.purchasesList[0])
        }
    }
}
```

How can i handle this situation properly? I thought about giving the user 3 credits anyway on the following month and remove 3 credits if suddenly the plan turns out a free plan, but I think this approach would be very abusable

Comment: Could you clarify please what are you worry about? Users will cancel subscription (trial period) then subscribe again to get trial period, right?

Comment: @Alex let's say the user subscribed for 1 month on my app, than he'll gain 3 credits to use some features, I can do it easily with PurchasesUpdatedListener. The problem is, i think he can renew the subscription outside the app I guess, or just set auto-renew, then after the renew he must gain 3 more credits, I don't know  how I can track this to keep giving him credits every renew of the currently subscription

Comment: @Alex currently I'm just tracking every loggin if his subscription are up, i can save the day he bought the subscription and the next month check if the subscription is there yet, but it seems wrong because the way I'm checking the subscription is cached by google play, so I'm not so sure how to give the user credits after every start of the period of the subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the most recent information about subscriptions you can use `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()` instead of `queryPurchases()`. You can combine it with your local caching algorithm to reduce abuse level. [Link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Query-recent)

**Warning:** queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() makes a network call, which could result in a charge to the app user.